# Why was my rude/abusive flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Yesterday, I flagged two answers on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12674/how-to-add-captcha-to-printer-e-mail-and-pdf-versions-email-form/) as rude/abusive. Both answers were by the same user (now deleted), [one of them](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/83701) contained gibberish of the 'cat-on-keyboard' type:

> [';'kljhgfdswdwfghjkwdqefghjkl;'

and [the other one](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/83700) used Chinese characters:

> 我很爱你，ad胡说八道是不好的会计年度南京发布电脑数据开放不会别的女尽可能sdfghjkl的法国红酒可怜

Google Translate gives me

> I love you, ad nonsense is not bad for the fiscal year Nanjing released computer data open no other female as much as sdfghjkl French wine poor

While this might not be a correct translation (as far as that is possible), it's clear somebody just entered some random Chinese characters (cat-on-Chinese-keyboard). In my opinion, this is gibberish as well and should be marked as rude/abusive. Now I'm looking at my flagging history, and I'm confused:

[image]

Could a moderator please explain why my flag on the first answer was marked helpful, but the second one declined? I'm trying to follow [community consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232):

> #### What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?
>
> ...
>
> *Abuse of the system or community* is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts that contain *no useful content at all* – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
> > asyuv;laergap897wertp[98 gb;vp98a34

Also, [Shog9 states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/295232) that it's fine to use any kind of flag for this:

> It's VLQ, it's abuse, it's Not An Answer

As I explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342847/4751173):

> For me the most important reason is that six rude/abusive flags cast by community members will automatically delete the post. This is more efficient than casting VLQ/NAA flags and having a ♦ moderator delete it; they can spend their valuable time solving problems the community can't solve on its own.

Comment: I seem to be affected, too.

Comment: I'm affected too. I'm not sure which of the two was declined, if it was the chinese gibberish or the european gibberish

Comment: Mine was declined as well. Looking at the answer url postid:245419 in the flagging history  and the link [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/83700) it was the chinese gibberish which was declined @rene

Comment: @suraj Hmm, okay. So I expect the outcome of this will be: *You should have flagged VLQ.* because the chinese text was translateable, not gibberish.

Comment: @rene That is what Shog9 says in his answer for https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/please-provide-a-flag-option-clearly-designed-for-gibberish-contentless-posts.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm reading that answer (and the many other answers from both Shog and other SE staff on the same topic) differently then from what you read in it. I don't see a *you shall not use abussive flags for that*, only as a  *heh, you have this other option as well*. Anyway, I guess I'll tweak or maybe even opt-out, my auto-flagging settings to prevent these mishaps for the future.

Comment: @rene _That said, there's now an alternative: Very Low Quality flags (available on any answer scoring 0 or less) kick the answer into the Low Quality review queue [...]._

Comment: I don't want this to end in a lesson in English comprehension. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @rene It's not an English lesson. Shog9 talked of VLQ flags, not me.

Comment: It's an *alternative*, so there is another good option: flagging as rude/abusive.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Okay, I'll accept that I might get some declined flags then when Smokey flags here for me. I think I'm still in the green. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: FWIW, the Chinese one, after the comma, *ad胡说八道是不好的会计年度南京发布电脑数据开放不会别的女尽可能sdfghjkl的法国红酒可怜* should come from the keystroke sequence ***adhsbdsbhdkjndnjfbdnsjkfbhbdnjknsdfghjkldfghjkl*** (middle row + BNM (last 3 keys from the bottom row)), so is it gibberish? Whoever reasonable should know.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer was automagically processed by the system, which marked the flags as helpful.

The second answer was handled by me.  I dismissed the **Rude/Abusive** flags as not helpful, as this post was rather neither rude nor abusive (and not spam for anyone wondering).  I marked the auto **Very Low Quality** and **Not An Answer flags** has helpful; both were appropriate.

This post did not require immediate attention from a diamond mod, which is that the **Rude/Abusive** flags triggered.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to quote the reason why [these kind of posts are considered abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232): *Abuse of the system or community is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts that contain no useful content at all – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of: asyuv;laergap897wertp[98 gb;vp98a34*. I agree that it ranks lower on the priority list than spam, but as I tried to explain, there are good reasons to use red flags here as well.

Comment: Your interpretation of this is at odds with Shog's then.

Comment: Yes, I would say my interpretation is different, but I can say that the final result for these posts and the user was the same.  If a post is auto-removed via **R/A** flags, then mods won't be able to act on the user as we probably  won't see the post deletion. Acting on the user itself is better for the site in the long run.

Comment: Gotta say I don't agree with Shog here either; rude and abusive should be reserved for posts that are actually rude or abusive IMO. I can sort of see how you might classify gibberish as "abusive to the site", but even that's a bit of a stretch. By the same logic you could easily argue that bad questions are just as, if not more, "abusive to the site", so they should all be flagged with rude or abusive too. "Rude" and "abusive" already have well-established English meanings, I don't think we need to tack other things on. Not when there are other flags that are more appropriate like VLQ

Comment: @Glorfindel your point about the automatic deletion makes a lot of sense on a site like SO, but we mods here aren't really overworked like the SO guys :) We don't get a lot of flags, and getting 6 on a single post that's anything other than spam is pretty  rare anyway (unless I'm mistaken and just haven't seen/handled those ones over the years). I'm not sure the "most important reason" from the question applies to Drupal Answers

Comment: @clive I'm happy your workload isn't that high; but still: in my opinion, the community can moderate these cases on its own. IIRC, there's something in The Theory of Moderation about moderators being exception handlers; those Meta posts seem to indicate this is regular moderation, just like closing questions.

Comment: @Glorfindel I wholeheartedly agree that the community _could_ moderate these cases on their own. But as I mentioned (or more implied I guess), for the most part they don't - if mods didn't do it, no one would. The exceptions get thrown much earlier around here than the bigger sites

Comment: I agree, and that's why we have [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) to help with (partially) automating moderation tasks for all sites across the network. We try to adapt to 'local' customs where that makes sense, but it's going to be hard to remember on which sites we can safely use rude/abusive flags for gibberish and for which sites not. I'm not worried about a single declined flag, but given the amount of spam on Drupal I don't want to risk a flag ban.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh I see, yes that makes a lot of sense. I hadn't really looked at it from that perspective. Well I'm personally more than happy to fall in line with Shog's interpretation of gibberish and rude/abusive, if only to make sure the charcoal crew don't get wrongly penalised, and I'll bring it up in the mod chat room later and see if we can all get on board with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Clive!

Comment: @mpdonadio Charcoal has [a tool](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/spammers/sites) for helping mods with finding spammers that aren't nuked yet.

Comment: Could the actual answer be updated to reflect (what I understand to be) the new synthesis? I believe there are at least four of us from Charcoal who are affected in this individual case, and more broadly probably dozens.

Comment: @tripleee This is the answer given from one of the moderators to _Why was just one of the flags marked as helpful?_ I don't see any new synthesis, and the answer already says what happened.

Comment: Here's another point for why these shouldn't be declined in the future: [`/help/mod-flags`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/mod-flags), paragraph near the bottom starting with "As a general rule of thumb". Can't copy the whole thing here because it's mod-only information, but it's pretty clear.

Comment: @Undo It also says _shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the network and the purpose of flagging_. If a user keep flagging as spam a comment posted as answer, or something the user things wrong, it's probable those flags from that user will be declined.